# Get only future events from calendar list in SharePoint 2013 Rest API

Tags: rest, calendar

I'm using SharePoint's rest api to get the coming events in a calendar, with the following query:

`/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Agenda')/Items?$top=3`

How can I change this query to get only events for which the `EventDate` is superior to today ?

Comment: Have you seen this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105576/rest-api-filter-by-start-and-end-dates-using-today ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `$filter` in your query URL

```
var today = new Date();

/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Agenda')/Items?$filter=EventDate ge '"+today.toISOString()+"'&$top=3
```

Following syntax is not needed. Only `ge '"+today.toISOString()+"'` is enough.

```
ge datetime'" + today.toISOString() + "'
```

Comment: This worked for me for columns like Modified and Created, but not for columns like EventDate and EndDate (400 error). For these fields I had to use this answer: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/136002/400

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot filter on the EventDate column with the $filter parameter in the REST api, you can use a Caml query like this:

```
var date = new Date();
$.ajax({
    url: "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Agenda')/getitems",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
        query: {
            __metadata: {
                type: "SP.CamlQuery"
            },
            ViewXml: "<View><Query><Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>" + date.toISOString() + "</Value></Gt></Where></Query><RowLimit>3</RowLimit></View>"
        }
    }),
    success: function (d) {
        console.log(d);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Comment: I got a 403 (FORBIDDEN) error

Answer (score 0):

You can get future only events for both recurring and non recurring events. Firstly you will have to create managed properties (in my case - `EventStartTime`, and `EventEndTime`) for both start date and end date of type date type (RefinableDate in SharePoint online) and the using them in your query text. To build search API query try using SPQuery builder tool on CodePlex.

By the way, query will be like below -

```
https://<<Site URL>>/_api/search/query?querytext='ListId:<<List ID>>'&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='Title,Description,DescriptionOWSMTXT'&refiners='ContentClass:STS_ListItem'&refinementfilters='or(and(EventStartTime:range(min," + new Date().toISOString() + ",to=\"le\"),EventEndTime:range(" + new Date().toISOString() + ",max,from=\"ge\")),EventStartTime:range(" + new Date().toISOString() + ",max,from=\"ge\"))'&rowlimit=100
```