# How many items (LIST) this current month

Tags: list, javascript, ajax, getlist

Its possible to know how many items will end this current month? with REST GET URL $filter=

Test GET URL: `/_api/lists/getbytitle('nameList')/items?$filter=Date_x0020_de_x0020_remise%272017-02%27`

list : how many item this month ?

```
id |  Name | date
 1 |  Test |  24/02/2017 00:00 <<<<<=======
 2 |  Test |  24/01/2017 00:00
 3 |  Test |  24/04/2017 00:00
```

return 1

Thx

Comment: What REST endpoint have you tried from the documentation? http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#FilterSystemQueryOption

Comment: i found $filter=start_x0020_Date le date time'2016-03-26T09:59:32Z' its only before or after the date but never this month (all month)

Comment: So what happens when you filter on **dates higher then previous months last day _and_ lower then next months first day** ?? (or this months first & last day if you do it with the 'le' and 'ge' statements)

Comment: i found a solution thx ! (count each item on current month on "success"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can be done in REST, but you could also add a Calculated column to your list in Sharepoint with the calculation =MONTH([Created]) and use that instead.

Add another column for the year ( =YEAR([Created]) ) so you can sort and filter over the years

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105576/rest-api-filter-by-start-and-end-dates-using-today but its only betwen tow dates :s